# Passing List Children to the Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
    

    
       I am new to React and trying to understand the basics. I have a child component called movieList that return a list of movies in a table form. 
    const movieList = () =>{ 
        const {movies} = props;
        return (){
        <tbody>
          <Fragment>
            {movies.map((movie, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{movie.title}</td>
              <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
              <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
              <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
              <td><button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick={props.onClick} movie={props.movie}>Delete</button></td>
    
            </tr>
            ))}
    
          </Fragment>
        </tbody>
        } }
    
    



  And the Parent
```

```html
class Movies extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { movies: getMovies(), }

        }

        handleDelete = (movie) => {
            console.log(movie);

        }


        render() {


            return (
                <MoviesList movies={this.state.movies} onClick={() => this.handleDelete(movie)} />
            );
        }
    }
```

I get the list of movies correctly on the table. But I want to target the button for delete on button click. I understand that I need to pass the movie as props from the child component movieList but I cant seem to figure out how to pass the movie for me to be able to delete. With the handleDelete function called on the onClick property, I get an undefined value on the console. Whereas I expect to get the value of a movie when I click. How can I do this in React.

Comment: Hi Olasunkanmi, try my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool so you have a list of movies and you just need to remove the right movie. We're going to try removing the movie it by its index in our array. We'll use the `array.filter()` method. See sandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-dan-uskcy

### Parent

```
class Movies extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: [
        { genre: { name: "Avengers: End Game" }, numberInStock: 100000, dailyRentalRate: 1 },
        { genre: { name: "Harry Potter" }, numberInStock: 20000, dailyRentalRate: 2 },
        { genre: { name: "DBZ" }, numberInStock: 200000, dailyRentalRate: 1}
      ]
    }; // assuming movies is an array
  }

  handleDelete = movieIndex => {
    const { movies } = this.state;
    const updatedMovies = movies.filter((movie, index) => {
      return index !== movieIndex;
    });

    this.setState({
      movies: updatedMovies
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MovieList movies={this.state.movies} handleDelete={this.handleDelete} />
    );
  }
}
```

So `handleDelete()` takes an index as an argument, and we use that to create a new array of movies, that do not include the movie with the index you passed in.

Then in the `.map()` of your `MovieList` component, we'll use the available index parameter as well, and pass that index inside the event-handler, `props.handleDelete(i)`. That will call the `handleDelete()` function defined in the parent component and it will update state.

### Child

```
const MovieList = (props) =>{ 
  const {movies} = props;
  return (
    <tbody>
    <Fragment>
      {movies.map((movie, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>
         <td>{movie}</td>
         <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
         <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
         <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
         <td><button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick={() => props.handleDelete(i)} movie={props.movie}>Delete</button></td>
          </tr>
       ))}
     </Fragment>
   </tbody>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the movie element through your callback. Change your child-components onlick to:

```
onClick={() => props.onClick(movie)}
```

Afterwards you need to pass the data from the callback to your function in your parent

```
onClick={movie => this.handleDelete(movie)}
```

or just

```
onClick={this.handleDelete}
```

Then all you need to do is remove the movie from the list in your state. React will then remove the element from the DOM:

```
handleDelete = (movie) => {
   const { movies } = this.state;
   const newMoviews = movies.slice();
   newMovies.splice(newMovies.findIndex(m => m.title === movie.title), 1)
   this.setState({ movies: newMovies });
}
```